# Odds & Evens Array Instantiation

Tags: java, arrays

We are learning arrays in class and I was assigned this programming project. I have wrote the code below so far but I am confused on how to get it to work properly. I am supposed to use a for loop with a System.out.println statement for my code.

Instantiate an array and load it with values. Write methods to determine how many
of the values in the array are odd and how many are even. The methods should return arrays that contain the
odds and evens

```
Sample Data :
 2 4 6 8 10 12 14
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 2 10 20 21 23 24 40 55 60 61

Sample Output :
 Odds - []
 Evens - [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
 Odds - [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
 Evens - [2, 4, 6, 8]
 Odds - [21, 23, 55, 61]
 Evens - [2, 10, 20, 24, 40, 60]
```

Here is My Code:

```
public class OddEvensHW {

public static void main(String[] args){

    int x = 0;
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

    System.out.println("Even : ");
    for ( x = 0; x  < numbers.length; x++); 
    {  
        if( numbers[x]%2 == 0){
            int even = numbers[x];
            System.out.print ( even + "\t");
        }
        else {
        }

        System.out.println(numbers[x] + " ");

    }

    // odds now
    System.out.println("Odds : ");
    for ( x = 0; x  < numbers.length; x++); 
    {  
        if( numbers[x]%2 != 0){
            int odd = numbers[x];
            System.out.print ( odd + "\t");
        }
        else {
        }         
    }
     System.out.println(numbers[x] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here: `for ( x = 0; x  < numbers.length; x++);` That semicolon at the end terminates the statement so that loop is basically doing nothing except for incrementing `x`. After that loop ends `x` has value `numbers.length` (which is `20` in this case) so when you reach `if (numbers[x] % 2 == 0) {` you'll get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `numbers[20]` lies outside the bounds. To fix this, simply remove the `;` from each `for` loop.

For your task you should write **methods** that **return** arrays with all odd and even numbers. So basically you need to have two methods, one for odds and one for evens.

To start with, they should look something like this:

```
public static int[] odds(int[] input) {
    int count = 0;
    //insert logic to count the odds in the input
    int[] odds = new int[count];

    // insert logic to fill the "odds" array with the odd values from "input"
    return odds;
}
public static int[] evens(int[] input) {
    // analogous
}
```

That should give you a basis to continue.

Answer (score 2):

for ( x = 0; x  < numbers.length; x++); is wrong you must delete the ";"

Answer (score 1):

> The methods should return arrays that contain the odds and evens

You return nothing.

1) You should return two arrays (odd array and even array) contained in a array.
The problem is that you cannot know before to iterate on it the size of each array and that an array is not dynamically extensible.
You could initialize the two arrays with the size of the initial array. The remaining elements will be null. 
Another solution would be to iterate a first time to count odd and even elements and instantiate the arrays by using this information and then to iterate again on the initial array to fill the two arrays.

2) You don't need to iterate twice on the initial array : one time to handle odd values and another time to handle even values.
You should rather handle the two cases (odd and even) during a single loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
```

This is because you in the couple of `for` loops, the loops runs till, `x < numbers.length`

```
numbers.length gives you the total number of entries in array. So in this case its 20, but the last index is 19 (it starts from 0 and ends at 19). Index 20 doesn't exist at all. Thus the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
```

To fix this, simple change the `for` to `for (x = 0; x < numbers.length - 1; x++)` in both Even and Odd cases.

Thus your code looks like:

```
public class OddEvensHW {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0;
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

    System.out.println("Even : ");
    for (x = 0; x < numbers.length - 1; x++)

    {
        if (numbers[x] % 2 == 0) {
            int even = numbers[x];
            System.out.print(even + "\t");
        }

    }

    // odds now
    System.out.println("Odds : ");
    for (x = 0; x < numbers.length - 1; x++)

    {
        if (numbers[x] % 2 != 0) {
            int odd = numbers[x];
            System.out.print(odd + "\t");
        }
    }

}

}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can do, As your loop was wrong it wasn't actually running. When it does you can collect data at once in single loop instead of 2 because either number will be odd/even where is not other possibility. So, `if-else` will do the work

```
 int x = 0;
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

    String even="";
    String odd="";

    for(;x<numbers.length;x++){
        if( numbers[x]%2 == 0){
            even += numbers[x] + ", ";
        }
        else {
            odd += numbers[x] + ", ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Even ="+even);
    System.out.println("odd ="+odd);
```